# Backing Up SQL Server To Cloud?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

To start i dont have much experience with DB's. In summary, i have an application for a client. They dont want to necessarilary host their DB online but have a local sql server set up for their 2 computers.

I have a batch script that backs up the database every night. Is there a way in the batch script to send them to the cloud like a skydrive,etc?

Answer (score 2):

Try our [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) software. You can schedule backup jobs with SQLBackupAndFTP (full, differential and transaction log backups), save backups at local folders, FTP, Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, Amazon S3, SkyDrive, delete old backups and configure email notifications... Basic features are available in free version or you can try all features in trial mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just backup to SkyDrive folder. If DB is big use rsync for sending to cloud or do full backups every week, differential every day and transaction every hour (depending of you application etc) then there will be less data to send to cloud.

Answer (score 1):

backup database to SD folder - using backup compression (if available in your edition of sql server, see WITH COMPRESSION clause of BACKUP statement help in BOL) or using 3rd party backup compression tool (either free or paid)

also you can backup database to temporary folder and then zip it to SD folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend a bit of money, cloudberry has an sql backup tool that will do exactly that (and more).

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/sql-backup-amazon-s3-azure.aspx